# How does OCaml know that = in apply_n f n x = ... is assignment whereas = in n = 0 is comparison?

Tags: ocaml

Question is as stated in title
How does OCaml know that = in apply_n f n x = ... is assignment whereas = in n = 0 is comparison?

Answer (score 4):

Definitions are introduced with the `let` keyword, which tips the parser that the next `=` is for a definition, not equality comparison.

```ml
# let f x y = x + y;;
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# f 1 2 = 1 * 2;;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: You do have to be a bit careful because something like `let to_string (type a) (module S : Stringable with type t = a) t = S.to_string t` would contain a different `=` before the definition one.